# Declaration under if clause, c++

Tags: c++, object

I wanted to create one instance of a class A when certain condition is satisfied. For example in following code, in the function B::fun() I wanted to create an object of class A if x == true. But if I define method as shown in type 1 the compiler says "a" is not declared. 
We can avoid error by defining this method as shown in Type 2. But in that case we will end up creating one instance of A which would not be used.

Please suggest any good way to handle this situation

```
class A {};

Type 1:
B::fun() {
 if (x == true)
       A a; 
}


Type 2 :
B::fun() {
     A a;  
}
```

Comment: `a` is declared, but only while you are inside the if-statement. It goes away again at the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

If the `A` will only be used when `x` is `true`, then use it in the same `if` block.

```
void foo()
{
   if (x == true) {
      A a;
      // use a now
   }
}
```

If this is not possible for whatever reason, then you will have to either:

- declare it outside of the `if`, as in your second example, and have it potentially unused; or
- use dynamic allocation.

Comment: 1. If I use method suggested by you then in that case I need to replicate huge amount of code.

Comment: I wanted to avoid dynamic allocation. As this method is called many time, I was thinking if I allocate it on stack then it might be fast. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta You are worrying about speed in code, that forces you to make such constructs? I would worry about design.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek.. I think you are correct. Design in more important.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: "Replicate" in what way? And why? Sounds like you have a design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Object `a`will be accessible inside `if`block only.
to use it outside, you can go with your second approach.

Comment: This answer just repeats the observations made in the question.